# Is this a bug or it is just a windows xp feature?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

Normally you can't make a folder with `/\:*<>"?` in its name. and also you can't name a folder `CON`,`LPT1` and .... and also you can't have two folder with equal name in a single directory.

I **THINK** I found a way to break all the above rules!

You just need to build a `New String` in the below path of registry :
`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\MUICache`

And name it `@WhatEverYouWant` (For example `@x`). Then set its value the name that you want to have for your directory! (For example `CON`,`LPT1`,`\/?:*<>|` and so on).

[image]

Then close the registry and create a new folder. it name the `@x` (The name that you selected for the string before) and hit enter. the name automatically change to the value of the string that you already created in Registy.

If you create a new folder again in the same path and set its name to `@x` again, you will have the second folder with the same name!

[image]

The above way works fine in **Windows XP**. I want to know if this is a bug or it is a feature? And what is the equivalent way in **Windows-7**?

**Update:**

This is output of `dir` command (When I was created just two `con` folder on desktop) :
[image]

Comment: Could you please `CD` to one of directories you have created and post a screenshot or the output of `DIR` command

Comment: @smc I checked it already. In `DIR` command, they have shown as `New Folder`, `New folder - Copy`,`New folder - Copy (2)` and so on!

Comment: ... which means you haven't actually created a folder called CON, LPT or /\:*<>"?. What you see on your desktop is just an alias name, but not the name of the folder

Comment: @smc Is it possible to do it in Windows-7 ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have windows 7, I am running XP at the moment. Lets wait and see, maybe someone else on SU will find time to test it for you. May I ask, what is the practical purpose of this?

Comment: @smc Just for fun. No practical purpose!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the output of your `Dir` command, you haven't *really* changed the filename. What's actually happening behind the scenes is that you are modifying your desktop.ini (a hidden, protected operating system file) file to *display* the string you defined in the registry, instead of the real directory name.

This is part of a feature to allow the localization of directory names (so you can display a different name depending on the user interface language) I don't know why Microsoft chose to make the behavior so easily accessible from Explorer, rather than requiring manual editing of the desktop.ini file though.